# How to display R Shiny output in R Markdown?

Tags: r, shiny, download, markdown

I'm new to R markdown here and I am trying to create an R Shiny app which I can enter a list of names, and then download the output (like a name list) as HTML file. I am using R markdown to create the HTML file. Here are my sample codes:

R Shiny:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- list(
  textInput("name", "Type new text input name", value = ""),
  actionButton("btn", "click me to create text input"),
  uiOutput("newInputs"),
  downloadButton("download_report", "Download")
)

server <- function(input, output)
{
  family_member <- reactiveValues(
    add_family_info = list()
  )

  observeEvent(input$btn, {

    newid <- paste(length(family_member$add_family_info))

    family_member$add_family_info <- c(family_member$add_family_info, list(c(newid, input$name)))

    family_member

  })

  output$newInputs <- renderUI({ 
    lapply(family_member$add_family_info, function(a)
      c(paste(a[2])))

  })

  output$download_report <- downloadHandler(
    filename = "name.html",
    content = function(file) {
      tempReport <- file.path(tempdir(), "name.Rmd")
      file.copy("name.Rmd", tempReport, overwrite = TRUE)

      params <- list(report = uiOutput("newInputs"))

      rmarkdown::render(tempReport, output_file = file,
                        params = params,
                        envir = new.env(parent = globalenv()))
    }
  )

}

runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

R Markdown:

```
---
runtime: shiny
output: html_document
params:
  report: NA

---
\
\

# Member names

`r params$report`
```

Appreciate any help! Thanks in advance!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just using a Shiny to render an Rmarkdown document, you don't need the runtime of the document to be Shiny. This is only needed if the document itself will ultimately be a shiny app.

Looking at the download handler

```
params <- list(report = uiOutput("newInputs"))
```

The `uiOutput` function generates the html for the element. It doesn't retrieve the values (you can see this if you run execute it in the console by itself). Additionally newInputs just refers to the container for the text (it's not actually inputs). Instead, you would want to use the reactive value storing the list

```
params <- list(report = family_member$add_family_info)
```

However, since this will be printed it can't be an arbitrary R object. It has to be something that `cat` can handle. In this case `family_member$add_family_info` is a list of list. Try flattening it with something like

```
params <- list(report = unlist(family_member$add_family_info))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! However, I am still not able to download the HTML file with the correct output :( Currently it displays the title "Member Names", without the list of name inputs in the Shiny app. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Edited my answer with some additional thoughts

Comment: I think there is a typo in your code, I assume you were to type params <- list(report=family_member$add_family_info)? The code still doesn't work though :(

Comment: Corrected the typo. What do you mean by not working? Is it generating a blank html document or is there any sort of error message?

Comment: The download button doesn't work, the report cannot be generated. There's a message in the console:
processing file: name.Rmd
  |................................................................................................................................................................................| 100%
   inline R code fragments

Quitting from lines 2-12 (name.Rmd) 

Warning: Error in vapply: values must be length 1,
 but FUN(X[[1]]) result is length 2
  [No stack trace available]

Comment: I think, especially given the format of your Rmd, you can only pass in R objects capable of being used by cat. Updated answer.

Comment: It works! Thanks! However with this code, for example if I input 2 names, e.g. John, Mary, the output would be " 0, John, 1, Mary".. I think the "0" and "1", comes from the 'newid' in the observeEvent.. any ways to remove this?

Comment: My bad, i could just remove the "newid" in the list! Thanks a lot for your help!